# Cannot figure out how to start PHP-FPM with Docker container

Tags: php, docker

I have a Docker container with PHP-FPM installed. To start it with -d option I tried this, but the container exits immediately:

```
docker run -d --name u12php53 -p 9001:9000 php53 /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.sh
```

The content of `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.sh` is:

```
service php5-fpm start && tail -F /var/log/php5-fpm.log
```

if I start the docker like this:

```
docker run -it --name u12php53 -p 9001:9000 -v php53
```

and start `php-fpm.sh` manually, `PHP-FPM` works fine and its log file is printed to stdout.

The final goal is to configure Docker to start my container with the system starts (or reboots).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here: `service php5-fpm start`. When you execute this command process php-fpm will be detached from shell. But Docker works only while main process is alive.

Try to run php-fpm as in [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/903540ea7918b5cabed6b32e81f8518f9e6f204f/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile): simply remove entrypoint and add `CMD ["php-fpm"]`.

Also, why do you want create your own php-fpm image? may be you can use [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image?

Comment: I need PHP 5.3 that is no longer supported, as far as I see. Isn't the main process /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.sh? it does not exit, because I use 'tail -F'. The other question is if I start docker with command 'docker run -d --name u12php53 -p 9001:9000 php53 yes', it does not exit.

Comment: thx, i understood what for you build own image. Main process must be started with `CMD` instruction. `Entrypoint` usually uses for preparing a container: configuration, make a migration, etc. Could you show me your Dockerfile please?

Comment: I described all the PHP-FPM installation procedure here https://developernote.com/2017/07/php56-in-docker-with-nginx-on-ubuntu16/ (there is also the Dockerfile). I started with PHP 5.6, but finally installed PHP 5.3 with the similar docker file based on Ubuntu 12.04. Looks like I cannot put this CMD into the Dockerfile, because I did the most of the installations steps manually with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the solution is:

```
docker run -d --name u12php53 -p 9001:9000 -v php53 bash -c '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.sh'
```

probably it is an equivalent of doing this in Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.sh"]
```